# How to check if a certain string repeats more than once in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my code, I want to check whether I could check if a certain string e.g

```
a="."
```

repeats more than once in a list. e.g

```
b=[".", ".", "Hello world"]
```

how would I do that?

Comment: `b.count(a) > 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
b=[".", ".", "Hello world"]
print(b.count(a))
>>> 2
```

Use `count` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built in `count` method

```
n_occurences = b.count(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `collections.Counter()` or simply `list.count()`

`list.count(x)` will return the count of `x` in `list`

```
b=[".", ".", "Hello world"]
# Check for "."
print(b.count(".")
```

`collections.Counter` will return a dictionary, which have `count` information of every item in a list:

```
from collections import Counter

b=[".", ".", "Hello world"]
# Check for "."
count = b.Counter() 

if count["."] > 1:
   print("More than one occurance")
```

Comment: I think `collections.Counter` is overkill for this case.

Comment: @sashaaero you are right. I've read OP carelessly and only come with the idea of using `Counter`. I've made an edit, `count()` is sufficient for such tasks :D

Answer (score 1):

Use count function.

```
    a="."
    b=[".", ".", "Hello world"]
    if b.count(a) > 1:
        print("more than 1 time")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

a = "."
b=[".", ".", "Hello world"]

print(Counter(b)[a]) # 2
```